# Heroku compile assets timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, asset-pipeline

since today I'm getting timeout exception on assets compile:

```
git push heroku
...
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
/app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in spawn': command='/app/slug-compiler/lib/../../tmp/buildpacks/ruby/bin/compile /tmp/build_nnx3b7xhbc6j /app/tmp/repo.git/.cache' exit_status=0 out='' at=timeout elapsed=900.1050653457642 (Utils::TimeoutError)
        from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:53:in `loop'
        from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:53:in `block in spawn'
        from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:48:in `popen'
        from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:48:in `spawn'
..
```

**Update:**

```
heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` by
heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`
heroku[run.7870]: Awaiting client
heroku[run.7870]: Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process
heroku[run.7870]: State changed from starting to complete
heroku[run.7870]: Process exited with status 128
heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started 
heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby/rails app
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My answer:** the issue was in non-ascii char in property, locally compilation went fine, but not on heroku. 
The bottom line - **use ascii only**

Answer (score 2):

Try precompiling assets locally.

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Also `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile` has to be set to false on Heroku.

See [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) for additional information.

Comment: That can work as quick fix, but not good at all as permanent solution

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the command git push heroku master?